# My audio is not working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, headphones

Here is my problem: I recently installed Ubuntu (dual boot alongside Windows).

When I tried to run a video or audio in Ubuntu, I don't hear anything. When I open settings and look into the sound tab, I see only my headphones, no speakers (even though they are not connected):

[image: The sound settings as seen]

When I am running PulseAudio to see my output devices, I see that the headphone option says it's plugged in even though it's not plugged in, and the speakers show as unavailable.

Can someone help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

In your operating system I think you have not updated driver plugins,
For that
Go to terminal and update and install plugin or VLC by typing

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc* y

That may be your solution

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings* → *Sound* and then change the profile to *Analog Surround 4.0 Output*.

Comment: i don't see any profile named like that. I only have Analog Stereo Output.

Comment: Me i have three profile names.